# Icon gloss after acceptance

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to remove the gloss from the icon with out having to resubmit? It seems silly that changing a simply 'NO' to a 'YES' would require an entirely new submission, but I cant seem to find out how this is possible. Can someone please assist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, need to submit again.

Answer (score 0):

The icon gloss is set in the app's `plist` file, and any change to the `plist` (or any other assets in the app) needs a re-submission. Once you submit an app, it's bundled up and nothing can be changed.